# Change className on keydown

Tags: javascript, css, class, onkeydown

I want to do so that when I press the button A the class of the element gets the same "class" as it gets on mouse over. (in CSS i have kay:hover to change the style ).

But I need to change the key to key:hover for specified classname.
Like onkeydown change style from "key C" to "key:hover C" :/

How do i achieve this effect?

Sorry if i explained badly :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED i just did

KEYDOWN: document.getElementById("keyC").className = "key2 C";
KEYUP: document.getElementById("keyC").className = "key C";

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
$('#area').keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == '65') {
        $('#elementToChange').attr('class', 'newClass');
    }
});
```

Where 65 is the keycode for the letter 'a'

Then add

```
$('#area').keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == '65') {
        $('#elementToChange').attr('class', 'oldClass');
    }
});
```

to set the class back to what it was when you release the 'a' button.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the keycode is not a string but a number. Besides that you should use `event.which` instead of `event.keyCode`. Quote from the jQuery docs: "While browsers use differing properties to store this information, jQuery normalizes the .which property so you can reliably use it to retrieve the character code."

Comment: This answer uses jQuery. Nothing wrong with that, but the question did not mention jQuery (or any other Javascript library) so you should make it clear.

Comment: can can I make this in pure JavaScript?